# Lag from filetype plugin indent on

Tags: indentation, performance

I'm getting lag in vim when navigating relatively small text files if `filetype plugin indent on` is uncommented in my vimrc file.  My full vimrc file is pasted below.  Any help on how I can get it enabled properly with no lag?  It's worked fine in the past. I only started having this issue lately.

```
set nocompatible          " We're running Vim, not Vi!
syntax on                 " Enable syntax highlighting

filetype off          " Begin For Vundle
set rtp+=~/.vim/vundle.git/
call vundle#rc()
Bundle 'gmarik/vundle'    
Bundle 'scrooloose/nerdcommenter'
Bundle 'scrooloose/nerdtree'

Bundle "https://github.com/msanders/snipmate.vim"
" End Vundle code

" causing massive lag, disabled
"filetype plugin indent on " Enable filetype-specific indenting and plugins

set number "enable line numbers
set lines=40 columns=100

set clipboard=unnamedplus

" Map ctrl-n to NerdTree
nmap <silent> <c-n> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>

" go to previous file with ,p
let mapleader = "," 
map <Leader>p <C-^> 

" Load matchit (% to bounce from do to end, etc.)
runtime! macros/matchit.vim

augroup myfiletypes
" Clear old autocmds in group
autocmd!
" autoindent with two spaces, always expand tabs
set ai sw=2 sts=2 et

" Move swp files to ~/.vim/tmp
set backupdir=~/.vim/tmp
set directory=~/.vim/tmp
```

Comment: I don't think that's what cause your problem but you start an autocommand group (`augroup myfiletypes`) but don't end it (`augroup END`) and it seems that to commands in it are not filetype specific. I don't know if that's an error in your copy-paste or an actual error in your vimrc but you might want to change that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think my issue was related to https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/1098 I've updated to vim 8.0 and it seems to have fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you have something in your actual syntax files causing the lag.
I'd reccomend running `:syntime on`, moving about a little, then doing `:syntime report`. This'll show you what patterns take the longest to check for matches. Consider disabling those, or looking them over if they're custom (usually stored in `~/.vim/after/`)

Comment: All I did was move the cursor, but here is the slow culprit. Any ideas how to fix? TOTAL      COUNT  MATCH   SLOWEST     AVERAGE   NAME               PATTERN
  7.582617   674    644     0.023922    0.011250  pythonFunction     \%(\%(def\s\|class\s\|@\)\s*\)\@<=\h\%(\w\|\.\)*